# I have 15 test Methods in my project but only 1 testcase is run when i run the project using cmd

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019, mstest

I am using Mstest frame work in Visual studio 2019. I have 15 testcases written in C#. I am executing these test cases using cmd

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" Test.dll
```

But when it executes only first test case is executed rest are skipped.

```
 //[Ignore]
    [Priority(1)]
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
    }

    //[Ignore]
    [Priority(2)]
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
    }
```

Could any one help?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[Priority]` attributes?

Comment: Still only one test case is executed rest are ignored @matthew